# Firefox ignores settings in userContent.css (sometimes)

Tags: firefox, browser

I have following code in my `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXXX.default/chrome/userContent.css`:

```
input, textarea {
color:#000  !important;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}
```

The purpose is to have input fields and text areas always black on white color. My desktop theme is dark and without this hack, firefox would display input and text area black text on dark gray backround, which is pretty much unreadable.

This works well for most websites, but some websites are still displayed as before (black text on gray background). For example [this website](http://uptime.is).

I have installed `dom inspector` and verified that the element is of type `input`. But why then are my css settings ignored for this site?

## SUBQUESTION:

Is there some documentation/manual, where these configuration options are explained? i.e. how do I know the keyword is `background-color` and not `background`? Also, what else can I configure other than `input` and `textarea` ?

Comment: Is that the box next to "Change SLA level:"? Instead of `background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;` could you try `background: #fff !important;`

Comment: @DK Bose - changing to `background:#fff !important;` makes no difference. The input on the [website](http://uptime.is/) is still black on gray.

Comment: Side note: /home/$HOME is not a valid path, since $HOME begins with /home itself.

Comment: @SkyDan - of course you are right. Thanks, I have corrected it it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that inputboxes are rendered defaultly by the operating system, not by the css-stylesheets. You can disable that by a Gecko-specific non-standard CSS property called `-moz-appearance`. Use it like this:

```
input, textarea {
  color:#000  !important;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  -moz-appearance: none !important;
}
```

Now, all your inputboxes where rendered by CSS.

## SUBQUESTIONS:

> Is there some documentation/manual, where these configuration options
>   are explained?

- [Mozilla Developer Network: -moz-appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)

> What else can I configure other than input and textarea ?

**Everything**, you want, there is also another file called `userChrome.css` (in the same folder) where you can customize the look of the user interface.

> How do I know the keyword is `background-color` and not `background`?

- `background-color`: Sets the background color of an element. Examples:

  ```
  background-color:red;
  background-color:#0000FF;
  background-color:rgb(255,0,255);
  ```
- `background`: Sets all the background properties in one declaration. Examples:

  ```
  background: #FF0000 url('blah.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  ```